# Creating an installer in Debian with Python

Tags: python, installation, debian

I would like to know if it possible to install a software from source code (from xxx.tar.gz) in Debian using any python library ?
Or by terminal, but I would prefer by python.

Im searching on the net but couldnt find any usefull info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TarFile.extract](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extract) and then use [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to execute `make` and `make install` if it exists in the tar.gz file.